# Django - Database design in orders ecommerce

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I have a scenario what will be best design for this .

**I have a Articles table (like pizza , drink etc)**

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE , blank=True, null=True)
    articlename = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)     #done
    articleoptionnames = models.ForeignKey(ArticlesOptionsName , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**2nd table is Article options (Like topping (1 time, 2times or 3 times), extra sauce ,  etc)**

```
class ArticlesOptions(models.Model):
    articleoptionrestaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE , blank=True, null=True)
    optionname = models.ForeignKey(ArticlesOptionsName, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="optionnames")
    min = models.IntegerField()
    max = models.IntegerField()
    choice_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.optionname)
```

**And 3rd Order table**

```
class orders(models.Model):
      restaurant=models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE , blank=True, null=True)
      articles=models.ForeignKey(Articles, on_delete=models.CASCADE , blank=True, null=True)
      articleoptions=models.ManyToManyField(ArticlesOptions)
      totalamount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

      def __str__(self):
          return str(self.articles)
```

Customer will be able to purchase many articles at a time and then every article have multipul article options (for example 4 types of topping and 4 type of sauce user can select many type of topping and many type of sauce ).  SO how to make  **order table** in best way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your order table should be split down further to be able to accommodate more than one article and article option. Your article options should be related to the article added to the order and not to the order itself. So, in my opinion, I think your order should look like this,

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

And add an order Article model which has the articles specific to that order each with their own option and each option has a quantity.

```
class OrderArticle(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Articles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class OrderArticleOption(models.Model):
    article_option = models.ForeignKey(ArticlesOptions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_article = models.ForeignKey(OrderArticle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply . I have to store quantity of article option as well . How I can say like    'Article1'  ->  'Article option2' -> quantity is 10   in order

Comment: You need to split your order options then and have the extra quantity field on it. check my updated answer.

Comment: got your logic thanks (Y)  . Last small thing how can I show all this data in this sequence in json in Django rest framework. I know how to do that . but now I have 3 tables . how to show data in sequence

Comment: The serializer in DRF should take care of this for you. I am not a DRF expert unfortunately, but I know it supports nested models like shown here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Comment: Glad I could help. Best of luck!